# Amazon cloud front caching is not working

Tags: cache, amazon-cloudfront

we have setup in such a way that end user request goes to Amazon cloud front and if cached resource is available on Amazon Cloud front otherwise it will forward request to origin (nginx server on Amazon EC2) and nginx request files from Amazon S3 storage service.

we have set up TTL in header as 5 Years in Amazon console.
according to documentation given in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html it should cache objects for 5 years.

documentation says "Objects are cached for the greater of 24 hours or the CloudFront Minimum TTL."

could anyone suggest where can be problem? how to troubleshoot this? according to our setting cloudfront should cache objects for 5 years.

Comment: What is your question? Why do you say the caching isn't working?

Comment: we have set TTL of 5 years so cloudfront should cache objects for 5 years but its not caching. I am seeking the reason why caching is not working?